# While using google map API and fetch from IP API to useState and passing to another component, I receive an error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Attempted to fetch from ip-geo-location.p.rapidapi.com to `const [ipInfo, setIpInfo] = useState({})` here how fetch?

```
const fetchInfo = async () => {
    const res = await fetch(url, options)
    const data = await res.json()
    setIpInfo(data)
  }
```

```
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchInfo().catch('somthing wrong with fetch');
  },[ip])
```

I get object

```
ipInfo =

{area
: 
{code: 'US-CA', geonameid: 5332921, name: 'California'}
asn
: 
{number: 141039, organisation: 'Packethub s.a.'}
city
: 
{geonameid: 5393015, name: 'Santa Clara', population: 126215}
ip
: 
"185.169.0.44"
location
: 
{latitude: 37.353, longitude: -121.9543}
postcode
: 
"95052"
status
: 
"success"
time
: 
{timezone: 'America/Los_Angeles', gtm_offset: -25200, gmt_offset: -25200, is_daylight_saving: true, code: 'PDT'}
type
: 
"IPv4"}
```

When trying to pass `ipInfo` to component and trying to fill fields there.
here is how I pass `ipInfo`:

```
<Output ipInfo={ipInfo}/>
{!isLoaded ? ('Loading...') : (<Map coordinates={[ipInfo.location.latitude,ipInfo.location.longitude]}/>)}
```

Here is the Output component:

```
const Output = ({ ipInfo }) => {
...
     <li>
        <p>ip address</p>
        <h2>{ ipInfo.ip}</h2>
      </li>
      <li>
        <p>location</p>
        <h2>{ipInfo.city.name}, { ipInfo.area.code.match(stateRegX)[0]} {ipInfo.postcode}</h2>
      </li>
...
}
```

I get an error and all the UI disappears until I delete all `ipInfo` in Output component
react-dom.development.js:18687.
and error says problem at Output {ipInfo} and at App problem with `const { isLoaded} = useLoadScript({ googleMapsApiKey:` (isloaded is from Google API)

The error displayed below occurred in the component:

> Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior. Visit https://reactjs.org/link/error-boundaries to learn more about error boundaries.
>
> at Output (http://localhost:5173/src/components/Output/Output.jsx?t=1692229578557:21:3)
> at div
> at App (http://localhost:5173/src/App.jsx?t=1692229339148:28:7)

I can't find adequate information regarding this error, I clicked on all errors it mentioned and it shows only `ipInfo` in Output and second link shows `useLoadScript` which is for Google Maps.